# Scheme/"The Seasoned Schemer": Question about the syntax of the definition of "try" function

Tags: syntax, scheme, seasoned-schemer

In their book "The Seasoned Schemer", Felleisen and Friedman introduce the `try` function. According to http://community.schemewiki.org/?seasoned-schemer, this function can be defined as

```
(define-syntax try
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((try var a . b)
     (letcc success 
       (letcc var (success a)) . b))))
```

where `letcc` is defined as

```
(define-syntax letcc 
  (syntax-rules () 
    ((letcc var body ...) 
     (call-with-current-continuation 
       (lambda (var)  body ... )))))
```

Now, while I understand what `try` does and how it can be used, I am having trouble to follow the formal definition of it. What exactly is the meaning of the dot in the application of `letcc` to `success` and `(letcc var (success a)) . b` in the lines

```
(letcc success 
       (letcc var (success a)) . b)
```

of `try`? Or maybe asked differently: Which part of the definition of `try` establishes that `try` is evaluated to `b` if `var` is called in `a`?

**Edit 1:** Sorry, the definition of `letcc` was incomplete. Added the missing first line.

**Edit 2:** The following code can be run in Racket.

```
(define-syntax letcc
   (syntax-rules ()
                 ((letcc var body ...)
                  (call-with-current-continuation
                    (lambda (var)  body ... )))))

 (define-syntax try
   (syntax-rules ()
                 ((try var a . b)
                  (letcc success
                         (letcc var (success a)) . b))))

(try var (+ 1 1) 4)
; output: 2

(try var (var '(2)) 4)
; output: 4
```

Comment: please paste a complete working code.  But you can use `unsyntax` in mit-scheme to see how the macro expander desugared the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax rules is pattern matching. A dot indicates the `car` and `cdr` of a pair just like rest arguments in `lambda` / `define`:

```
(define (my-list . args)
  args)
```

A list is just nested pairs. eg. `(1 2 3)` is just fancy way of displaying `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))`.

So `(this is random symbols in a list)` will match `(try var a . b)` by `try` matching `this`, `is` matches `var`, `random` matches `a`, and `(symbols in a list)` matches `b`.

When you see the same in the expansion it means the code should splice the match after the dot. Eg `(var . b)` with the previous example becomes `(is symbols in a list)`. It is similar to having `b ...` but cheaper for the system.

Comment: Thanks; unfortunately, that is not what I am asking. I understand what the dot in the pattern `(try var a . b)` means but my question is about the dot two lines below that pattern.

Comment: Thanks again, the last paragraph now answers my question about the dot in the expansion, i.e. that it is a splicing instruction. Do you happen to know where this expansion rule is explained in any of the Scheme language references?

Comment: @J.Hauser not an instruction. If you give `'(a . b)` as code to the reader it will do a `(cons a b)` either in the compiler or runtime. The replacements having `(a b)` would mean `(cons a (cons b '()))` while `(a . b)` would be `(cons a b)` and when the reader has read the syntax-rule it is already consed. Thus during the expansion it just replaces the symbols it finds verbatim copying the structure with the "bindings" of the code. [The reference doesn't use much time on `.` at all.](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.19)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on the intricacies of Scheme macro syntax, but I *think* an equivalent definition of `try` is:

```
(define-syntax try 
  (syntax-rules () 
    ((try var a b ...) 
     (letcc success 
       (letcc var (success a)) b ...))))
```

I find this much easier to read for sure.

`(try e <a> <b> <c>)` (either version, at least in Racket) then expands to

```
(letcc success
  (letcc e
    (success <a>))
  <b> <c>)))
```

So, then, when `<a>` is being evaluated, `e` is a continuation which returns its arguments from the inner `letcc` form, where they're ignored.  If `e` is invoked that's where you end up and then `<b>` and `<c>` get evaluated in the normal way (I've only put more than one thing there because I can, and it deals with the whole `.` `...` thing).  if `e` *isn't* invoked during the evaluation of `<a>`, then `success` *is* invoked, and it's also a continuation which then returns the result of evaluating `<a>` from the whole form.

At least I think that's what happens.

---

Below is a chunk of Racket which I used to test I understood things.

```
(module+ test
  (require rackunit))

(define-syntax let/cc 
  (syntax-rules () 
    ((let/cc var body ...) 
     (call-with-current-continuation 
       (lambda (var) body ... ))))) 

(define-syntax try 
  (syntax-rules () 
    ((try var a b ...) 
     (let/cc success 
       (let/cc var (success a)) b ...))))

(module+ test
  (check-eqv?
   (try fail (+ 1 1) 4)
   2)

  (check-eqv?
   (try fail (fail '(2)) 4)
   4)

  (check-eqv?
   (try fail
        (begin 1 (fail) (error "failed to fail"))
        4 5 6)
   6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try and see what happens.  I am using mit-scheme.

File try.scm:

```
(define-syntax letcc
  (syntax-rules ()
     ((letcc var body ...)
      (call-with-current-continuation
          (lambda (var)  body ... )))))

(define-syntax try
  (syntax-rules ()
     ((try var a . b)
      (letcc success
        (letcc var (success a)) . b))))

(try var (+ 1 1) 4)

(try var (var '(2)) 4)
```

First step: you compile the file:

```
> (sf "try")
```

This will generate the `try.bin`.

Second step, print the desugared syntax:

```
> (pp (unsyntax (fasload "try")))


;Loading "try.bin"... done
 ................
 (call-with-current-continuation
  (lambda (success)
    (call-with-current-continuation 
        (lambda (var) (success (+ 1 1))))
    4))
 (call-with-current-continuation
  (lambda (success)
    (call-with-current-continuation 
        (lambda (var) (success (var '(2)))))
    4)))
```

Now you see explicitly what is executed, hence the result.

In the case of `(try var (+ 1 1) 4)` you jump out 2 nested `calcc`, as you call `success` with value `2`, while in the `(try var (var '(2)) 4)` you jump out 1 level and the `4` from the sequence of the 1st continuation will be returned.